# Android: Как записать дату прямо в видео?

Tags: android, камера, видео

Хочу в каждый кадр видео, которое записывается вставить дату. Фактически нарисовать ее и потом только кадр отдать на предпросмотр и запись. Читал, что это делается через метод `onPreviewFrame`, который получает массив `byte[]` с кадром. Как его отредактировать?

Answer (score 3):

Данные полученные через `Camera.PreviewCallback()` невозможно изменить. Вы просто получаете доступ к битовым данным с которыми можете делать все что угодно, кроме как отправить назад измененными.

Answer (score 1):

Довольно нетривиальная задача. И довольно непонятная в плане "зачем". Если нужно делать это на лету, то нужно как минимум знать формат видео(побайтово), а если не на лету, то получайте каждый кадр в виде картинки и вам нужно будет знать всего лишь формат картинки(побайтово).

Зная формат вы сможете вставить данные в нужное место, не потеряя других.

Comment: Пишу на диплом приложение и его часть - это по сути видеорегистратор. И хочется записывать видео сразу с датой, как это сделано, собственно, в видеорегистраторах, чтобы при воспроизведении этого видео где-нибудь в углу, например, отображались время и дата.
Реально ли это сделать?

Comment: @FoX4: раз видеорегистратор может, и вы сможете.

Comment: Если можно, хотелось бы поконкретнее... Как это сделать, какими методами? Реально ли через onPreviewFrame обработать кадр и выдать на запись и в предварительный просмотр?